# Selenium Grid connection errors and timeout exceptions

Tags: python, selenium

My team and I have been having some trouble with our testing infrastructure. We have test suites that run against different browsers on different platforms using different provisioned settings -- all of which works just fine. Our only issue is that from time to time, we run into strange connection failures and session errors.

Our connection failure deriving from `urlib2`, which the official selenium bindings are communicating with

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Is occurring across all browsers on both our Windows and Mac nodes.

A well as our session related error,

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Session [insert-session-id-here] was terminated due to TIMEOUT
```

---

Giving some context, we have 5 maximum sessions on our windows node with 5 max instances for chrome and firefox. Our tests also run in parallel.

The connection error only occurs when we have our hub/nodes running for an extended period of time. I've found that shutting down the hub using the lifecycle manager and starting it back up seems to do the trick -- until the error appears again.

The session error occurs across different tests on different browsers unexpectedly. From what I've read it may be due to parallelization, but I have no idea what the root cause is.

**Hub Configuration**
https://pastebin.com/17VQHbrA

**Node Configuration**
https://pastebin.com/XDit2yT1

Comment: Are your tests running in separate threads each with their own webdriver instance? Do the timeouts occur randomly across all nodes and browsers and tests? Or is there a pattern? Have you tried setting higher timeout values?

Comment: Each test is running in it's own thread , we're using the nose test runner. Each test created a new instance of a remote webdriver.

The timeouts occur randomly across nodes, browsers, and tests. We can't seem to find a common factor.

We have tried changing `browserTimeout` and `timeout` to no avail.

Comment: Hmm. You said restarting the hub helps. Does that mean restarting the nodes instead makes no difference, and restarting the hub without restarting the nodes avoids the timeouts? Is the hub running into resource/performance constraints?

Comment: You're not seeing lots of dead driver processes on the nodes, are you? Or high load for that matter? I assume not, but should rule it out.

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging for the hub and nodes to see if any warnings or errors appear?

Comment: Correct, it seems restarting either node doesn't seem to make a difference. I had originally believed it to be a performance problem on the Hub's part, but it's running on a very beefy EC2 machine that should be more than capable of doing the job.

I should also add we're using a dockerized hub, but we've made sure the server we're using for our nodes is compatible.

As for webdrivers, are tests are killing our browsers/drivers correctly without fail -- we had the same theory.

Regarding the logs, I actually do not believe so -- I can't believe this slipped my mind.

Comment: I'll go ahead and turn logging on for both the hub and nodes now, and report back when I have some results. Thank you!

Comment: The connection error seems to be due to network congestion, after carefully debugging the problem. The hub/node logs did not contain any useful information -- but I realized (using a packet sniffer), that the packets were getting lost being sent to our ESX machine.

We'll have to rework our infrastructure, but I now know the cause. Thank you for your help!

Comment: np, glad you figured it out!

Comment: @neet_jn in a different infrastructure we too are having the same issue. Did you find the solution?